# What's the best value Java object database?

Tags: java, database, object

What's the best value Java object database out there that has:

- Ease of use: one line of code to
  store any object.
- Efficient memory usage: i.e. only
  loads the things that are called for,
  not the whole object every time (i.e.
  "Transparent Activation").
- Automatically change objects when
  manipulated (i.e. "Transparent
  Persistence").
- Native querying (no need for SQL,
  JDOQL etc.)
- Free

where anybody has experience with the following:

- Neodatis
- db4o
- JODB
- joafip
- MyOODB

?

Comment: db4o .... it has everything you've listed.  Plus, it is supported by a public company, so will not disappear and it is being used by many many companies ... Sony, Savi, CISCO, etc... over 100,000 community members.

Answer (score 4):

I can only answer for db4o. I don't have enough experience with the other databases you've named.

- Ease of use: I think that db4o is very easy to use in many scenarios. You add the db4o jar to your project, open the database and [start storing and querying objects](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/object_container.htm).
- Efficient memory usage: Yes, db4o can do that. It supports [transparent activation](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/activation_concept/transparent_activation_framework.htm). In that mode db4o loads only objects which you are actually using.
- Automatically change objects when manipulated: Is also [supported](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/update_concept/transparent_persistence.htm).
- Native querying: Yes db4o [supports](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/querying/native_queries.htm) that. Native queries are great and powerful. However in practice complex native queries often cannot be optimized and run slow. In such cases you have to fall back to less elegant SODA queries.
- It's free under a GPL licence.

Another advantage of db4o that has a community which can help and share knowledge.

Do you have a particular use case scenario for the database? I think that you should pick the database which fits you're application the best.

Comment: Don't forget that the build-time query optimizer gives great feedback on whether a NQ is too complex to be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used [HyperGraphDB](http://www.hypergraphdb.org/), which satisfies all your requirements. I am pretty impressed with it: "HyperGraphDB is a general purpose, open-source data storage mechanism based on a powerful knowledge management formalism known as directed hypergraphs. While a persistent memory model designed mostly for knowledge management, AI and semantic web projects, it can also be used as an embedded object-oriented database for Java projects of all sizes. Or a graph database. Or a (non-SQL) relational database."

Comment: Recommend it too, just add the library jar and start using the graph database without the need to run a separate database server process.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Redis:

http://redis.io/clients

It has Java clients and from personal experience, Java objects map better to Key-Value based databases than Relational DBs but YMMV depending on your usage patterns and types of data.

**Note:** It may not cover all of your requirements above, but you could probably add such functionality yourself fairly easily.

**Update:** https://github.com/xetorthio/johm

Comment: I don't think that's an object database software, is it?

Comment: It's not strictly an Object DB, but with hash support and good client software, it can behave as one.

Comment: @Navigateur: actually that ain't really an issue seen that 99% of Java programs out there aren't OO programs ;)  Think about this: *equals* and *hashCode* are present at the top of the Java OO hierarchy and yet they're fundamentally incompatible with inheritance (this is very nicely demonstrated in Joshua Bloch's *"Effective Java"*).  Thing is: people use Java "objects" but they don't do OO.  That is why collections such as maps and sets work (they wouldn't if inheritance was involved, because *equals* and *hashCode* are incompatible with inheritance) and that is why key/value store rocks...

Comment: I have data with a deep interlinked structure (many levels deep). How, in a nutshell, should/would I handle that? (I have no idea about using key-value databases).

Comment: Lazy loading should do the trick, you load nested instances on demand. Suppose an instance of class A has an internal list holding many instances of class B: When writing the contents of class A to redis, replace any instance of class B with a key instead of storing a serialized version of each instance of B directly under the value of the class A instance. When reading the class A instance from redis, you can choose to only load the nested B instances when you need them, since you already have the redis key available. You can take a look at ohm (http://ohm.keyvalue.org/) for a general idea.

Comment: Oh the noise of ...good enough.  Key-Value stores, yeah, good enough if you want to hard code all your data access logic for every use case.  At least a document store will give meta data layer and allow you to do some simple queries and clean out half your code that should be handled by your database.  Still, don't know why anyone would want to have it half way ... use an ODB, you can have key-value partitioning for simple, isolated, embedded data scaling and query and have aggregations of your simple data fully connected in an OO model on the solution side for your structured data.